# WebSQL Select Rows from two Tables

Tags: sql, web-sql

I have two tables, one that records transactions and another that contains previous transactions, I need to be able to store the sum grouped by Reference. How can I select rows from two tables in webSQL?

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT SUM(Qtt) AS QttSumByREF, Ref from OrderMoves, CurrentMobileOrderMoves WHERE CompanyID = ? GROUP BY Ref
```

But this does not work.

Tables both have Ref, CompanyID, Qtt columns. CurrentMobileOrderMoves has additional columns that are not relevant to the operation.

OK I figured out how to Select all the rows using UNION:

```
SELECT Ref, Qtt from OrderMovesWhere CompanyID=? UNION ALL SELECT Ref, Qtt From CurrentMobileOrderMoves Where CompanyID=?
```

Now How can i group them by Ref and Do a SUM of the Qtt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the your above **Union all** query into subquery and top of that result you can have `group by` clause, as below -

```
select ref, sum(Qtt)
  from (SELECT Ref, Qtt
          from OrderMovesWhere CompanyID = ?
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Ref, Qtt From CurrentMobileOrderMoves Where CompanyID = ?) as t_1
 group by ref;
```

Comment: I eventually figured out the answer, and it's the same as your code. So I am validating the answer ;)